# How to calculate projectile motion with unit directional vector

Tags: math, graphic, projectile

i have already found the math for dealing with projectile motion but the different with mine was the directional vector and time provided.

In my code , my directional vector was -1 to 1 and time was an interval time.

How do I use those vector and time to calculate the new directional vector due to gravity?

Please help

Comment: Please, describe the problem better. What is a vector -1 to 1????

Comment: A good idea would be to add some info about space (axises directions , dimensions,planar/spherical gravity field ...) also velocities are important, you want newtonian/D'Lambert mechanics or relativistic effects also ...btw I saw here quite a few questions about bullet physics try search with [bullet] tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume 3D space (with gravity directing in -Y direction)

1. **init**

   ```
   // player / gun parameters
   const float v0 = ???;             // [m/s] gun projectile escape velocity
   float direction[3] = { ?,?,? };  // [-] your unit direction vector
   float position[3] =  { ?,?,? };  // [m] your player position + gun barrel offset

   // projectile parameters
   float a[3]={0,-9.81,0};   // [m/s^2] actual acceleration (just gravity in down direction)
   float v[3]=direction*v0;  // [m/s] actual velocity
   float p[3]=position;      // [m] actual position
   ```

   if you want to be precise add to v also your players velocity vector. If your projectile is rocket then add to a also its trust acceleration in its direction ...
2. **update in some timer**

   ```
   const float dt = 0.001; // [s] update 'timer' period

   v += a*dt;
   p += v*dt;
   ```

   here you can add tests like: hit something, hit ground, ... also friction is a good idea ...

   ```
   F=c0*|v|^2; for air
   F=c1*|v|^3; for liquid
   ```

   in direction `(-v/|v|)` so add to start of update this:

   ```
   a={0,-9.81,0}
   a-=v*c0*|v|/m; // or a-=v*c1*|v|^2/m;
   ```

   where `c0,c1` are friction constants (try `~0.01`) and `m` is the projectile mass [kg]